# Acceleo standalone generation

Tags: acceleo

I also need to generate outside eclipse and i didn't figured out how to do it.
I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118377/standalone-acceleo-generator) but I have another problem to overcome first : I'm unable to start the main !

I tried different ways : export the project as standalone, put the project in a regular or executable jar, and launch directly Generator.class. I would like some help with the last solution. Here's how I launch it :

> java -cp "..\testGene\bin\;C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins" testGene.main.Generate testModel.uml outputDir

I can't copy the whole console (dev computers are not connected to internet), but it says :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/Eclipse/acceleo/engine/service/AbstractAcceleoGenerator
>   
>   Could not find the main class: testGene.main.Generate.

The generator works well inside eclipse, and I manage to call a simple test class with the same command line. I tried to copy the whole acceleo plugins in my bin directory in case the space in "Program Files" is a problem.

I'm pretty sure this is a simple error I made, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, I'm not sure that it's sufficient to use the plugins folder in your classpath. Shouldn't there be a list of the jar files you need?

Comment: You are right, I added all those jar one by one in the class path and now java finds the main class.

Comment: Then I had to use the commented code to register the uml resource factory and import the jar.

Now it works fine, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Since the program does not seem to find the `AbstractAcceleoGenerator` I would say that you are lacking some dependencies of the generator. Have a look at [this screenshot](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-UmFfN542A3Q/TowUM8OJkFI/AAAAAAAAAiw/zF6T2Q8-5ZY/AcceleoStandAlone.png) to see the jar used for an UML to Java generator.